# c# stopwatch.startnew() always returns 0

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I have this loop that I want to measure the speed of:

```
        private static string[] sequentialTest(string[] thisstringlist)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        string[] returnList = new string[2150];
        for (int i = 0; i < thisstringlist.Length; ++i)
        {
            int thisI = i;
            returnList[i] = thisstringlist[i] + "pluuus this";
        }
        int thiss = 0;

        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("execution time" + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        return returnList;

    }
```

Should be really simple, the stopwatch should just measure how long this operation takes, but i keeps returning 0

I have also tried inserting thread.sleep(), just to force the code to take some time, but that doesnt work either

Comment: How big is thisstringlist? prove it to your self (that it returns 0), by break pointing the method. I doubt this is a bug in the BLC, and more likely just your assumptions. And lastly this is not a good way to benchmark code. use a benchmark framework

Comment: the list is a little bit bigger than 2000 elements which one of assunptions do you think it was?

Comment: I think the method is running sub-millisecond, put a `Thread.Sleep(100)` in there to prove it, or break point it

Comment: ah, yes. but shoudnt it work then when I add the thread.sleep(5000)?

Comment: You might try using ElapsedTicks instead of ElapsedMilliseconds to see if things are working.

Comment: Uhhhh..., `returnList` is an ARRAY ;-)

Comment: Just use `watch.Elapsed`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As the name suggests, a stopwatch needs to be *stopped* in order to see all these values, as shown in the documentation as well. So in order to fix this, write `watch.Stop();` before `var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;`.

**Note**: in newer versions of .NET framework `stop` is not required.

Also, check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: ehm "*You can query the properties Elapsed, ElapsedMilliseconds, and ElapsedTicks while the Stopwatch instance is running or stopped. The elapsed time properties steadily increase while the Stopwatch is running; they remain constant when the instance is stopped.*"

Comment: thank you very much, this works, even though the loop is still sub milliseconds

Comment: @MichaelRandall good looking! The thing is, it is as far as I believe a new feature, as I was working with Stopwatch in the past and had the same issues. Also for consistency sake (to not take into the account printing speeds, although they are little), it is better to stop the watch imho

Comment: @s3j80 Please mark it is the right answer if I helped (also as noted above you can just write this on a newer .net framework)

Comment: @ho4upivo Please correct your answer.. `stop` is not needed. It will be confusing to future user.

Answer (score -1):

```
 private static string[] sequentialTest(string[] thisstringlist)
    {
     Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
      stopwatch.Start();
      string[] returnList = new string[2150];
        for (int i = 0; i < thisstringlist.Length; ++i)
        {
            int thisI = i;
            returnList[i] = thisstringlist[i] + "pluuus this";
        }
        int thiss = 0;
       Console.WriteLine("execution time" + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
      stopwatch.Stop();
   }
```

Comment: WhY declare the Stopwatch outside the method? No advantage but you are calling for troubles if (or when) multithreading enter in the picture